# Cypher: Match random node in Neo4j

Tags: random, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a database with 3.4 millions of nodes and want to select a random node.

I tried using something like

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE rand() <= 0.01
RETURN n 
LIMIT 1
```

but it seems like the algorithm always starts with the same nodes and selects the first one whose random number is below 0.01, which means in most cases the "random" node is one of the first 100 checked nodes.

Is there a better query, to select a completely random one of all my nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You could generate an random ID from the `rand()` function and  multiply it by the number of nodes. This should generally return a more random node.

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE id(n) = toInteger(rand() * 3400000)
```

Once there is some space created within your nodes (i.e. they are no longer perfectly contiguous due to deletes) you might miss a few here and there. In that case you could always range the random number +/- a few on either side and return the first row of the result.

```
WITH toInteger(rand() * 3400000) AS rand_node, 5 AS offset
WITH range(rand_node - offset, rand_node + offset) AS rand_range
MATCH (n) 
WHERE id(n) IN rand_range
RETURN n
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what about If I want to match a randomly select a node from a specific type. For example randomly select a movie ?

Comment: I would add `:Movie` to the  match statement `MATCH (n:Movie)...` and play with increasing the offset used to be a higher number until I started getting consistent hits on random movies.

Comment: ID values might be distributed or totally random

Comment: yep, they might be clustered, distributed, some clustered, some distributed, who knows. you could do some sampling and do a full table scan of `:Movie` to see what you have to give you some idea. you could give every movie some kind of identifier and randominze just that namepsace...

Answer (score 0):

This works, returning variations on successive runs. Query performance with 3.4 million nodes may or may not be acceptable though.

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```